# shell bash, cat file whilst using sed to replace text

Tags: string, shell, sed, grep, cat

With the help of SO I have been able to correct my sed command so I can use variables (was using ' instead of " and wasn't using g for global).

However, I am struggling to get the command to work correctly.

To give you some context, I have a file containing numerous lines of text and some line contain one or more tags. these tags are in the following format:

```
[#$key#] - i.e #[#] is used to indicate the presence of a key
```

Then I have an internal array object which stores a string value which contains each key and a corresponding value in the following format:

```
$key=$value
```

What I am trying to do is to cat my file containing the tags at the same time as using a global sed replace to swap the $key for the corresponding value within the array object.

The problem I have is that my grep/sed command is not replacing any of the text and I can't figure out why.

here is my code:

```
for x in "${prop[@]}"
do
     key=`echo "${x}" | cut -d '=' -f 1`
     value=`echo "${x}" | cut -d '=' -f 2`


    # global replace on the $MY_FILE
    cat $MY_FILE | sed "s|\[#${key}#\]|${value}|g" > ${TEMP_MY_FILE}
    cat $TEMP_MY_FILE > $MY_FILE

 done
```

I thought about using sed -i, but my version doesn't seem to support-i

Comment: No need to `cat file | sed > new_file`. Instead, do `sed ... file > new_file`.

Comment: You seem to have a problem with the lines that set `key` and `value` as well, which I would think would cause some errors.

Comment: the key and value variables are as expected-have echo'd them to double check

Comment: use `set -x` at the beginning of your script and debug it this way

Comment: For future reference, `sed -i ... inputfile` is simply a shortcut for `sed ... inputfile > tmpfile; mv tmpfile inputfile`. It just saves you  having to state it explicitly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `[` doesn't have any special meaning in a double-quoted bash string, `\[` still evaluates to `[` since backslashes are processed to allow for escaping dollar signs. Try

```
sed "s|\\[#${key}#\\]|${value}|g"
```

as your `sed` command. The double backslash will causes a literal backslash to be sent to `sed`, which will use it to escape the `[` to treat it literally as well.

Comment: my version (on solaris) doesnt support -i I'm afraid

Comment: when I use set -xv on the script it seems to interpret the $key string within the grep as *\[\#\e\x\a\m\p\l\e\_\k\e\y\#\]* instead of [#example_key#]